# how to replace time zone in tabel use php, I try preg_replace() but show error

Tags: php, timezone, preg-replace

I have data from the database in the form of datetime and timezone, but I want to not display the timezone in a table using php, I have tried using preg_replace but there is an error, is there another solution?

this is my data in data tabel on php

```
28-11-2019 11:03:48 +0700
```

this is my code in php

```
        $c_date= $row['creationdate'];
        $c_date = preg_replace("+0700");
```

This is message error

```
Warning: preg_replace() expects at least 3 parameters, 1 given in D:\XAMPP\xampp\htdocs\cash_management\user_payroll_approval.php on line 177
```

Comment: [RTFM](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Answer (score 1):

If preg_replace is used, you must be familiar with regular expressions. 
preg_replace requires at least 3 parameters. Look in the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). Hence the error.

Use str_replace, which is easier if the time zone is always +0700.

```
$strDate = "28-11-2019 11:03:48 +0700";

$strDate = str_replace(" +0700","",$strDate);
var_dump($strDate);
//string(19) "28-11-2019 11:03:48"
```

More flexibility and clarity is achieved by using the DateTime class.
You can customize the format to your liking.

Example:

```
$strDate = "28-11-2019 11:03:48 +0700";

$strDateFormat = date_create($strDate)->format('Y-m-d H:i');

var_dump($strDateFormat);
//string(16) "2019-11-28 11:03"
```